# Autocomplete Textbox from Active Directory usind LDAP Users in php

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, ldap

I am trying to autocomplete a field that picks names of users from LDAP. My codes are as follows :

**index.php**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search-box").keyup(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "readCountry.php",
      data: 'keyword=' + $(this).val(),
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#search-box").css("background", "#FFF url(LoaderIcon.gif) no-repeat 165px");
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#suggesstion-box").show();
        $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
        $("#search-box").css("background", "#FFF");
      }
    });
  });
});

function selectCountry(val) {
  $("#search-box").val(val);
  $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 610px;
}
.frmSearch {
  border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
  background-color: #C8EEFD;
  margin: 2px 0px;
  padding: 40px;
}
#country-list {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 190px;
}
#country-list li {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  border-bottom: #F0F0F0 1px solid;
}
#country-list li:hover {
  background: #F0F0F0;
}
#search-box {
  padding: 10px;
  border: #F0F0F0 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <TITLE>jQuery AJAX Autocomplete - Country Example</TITLE>

  <head>

    <body>
      <div class="frmSearch">
        <input type="text" id="search-box" placeholder="Country Name" />
        <div id="suggesstion-box"></div>
      </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**readCountry.php**

```
                <?php

            if(!empty($_POST["keyword"])) {

            $Name=$_POST["keyword"];
            $username="********";
            $password="********";
            $lc = ldap_connect("********") or
            die("Couldn't connect to AD!");
            ldap_set_option($lc, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
            ldap_bind($lc,$username,$password);
            $base = "OU=********,DC=********,DC=********";
            $filt = "(&(&(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(name=$Name*))))";
            $sr = @ldap_search($lc, $base, $filt);
            $info = ldap_get_entries($lc, $sr);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $info["count"]; $i++) {
            $info[$i]["cn"][0] ;
            }
            if ($i == 0) {
            echo "No matches found!";
            }

            if(!empty($info[$i]["cn"][0])) {
            ?>
            <ul id="country-list">
            <?php
            foreach($info[$i]["cn"][0] as $country) {
            ?>
            <li onClick="selectCountry('<?php echo $country ?>');"><?php echo   $country ?></li>
            <?php } ?>
            </ul>
            <?php } } ?>
```

**What I have :**

This isn't returning names from LDAP nor is there any error that is dispalyed for me to fix it.

**What I need :**

[image]

When A is typed, all the names starting with 'A' should be shown in the dropdown.

Appreciate any help :) Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way out! Just had to change the onclick in readcountry.php as shown below :

```
                <?php

        if(!empty($_POST["keyword"])) {

        $Name=$_POST["keyword"];
        $username="********";
        $password="********";
        $lc = ldap_connect("********") or
        die("Couldn't connect to AD!");
        ldap_set_option($lc, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
        ldap_bind($lc,$username,$password);
        $base = "OU=********,DC=********,DC=********";
        $filt = "(&(&(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(name=$Name*))))";
        $sr = @ldap_search($lc, $base, $filt);
        $info = ldap_get_entries($lc, $sr);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $info["count"]; $i++) {
       <li onClick="selectCountry('<?php echo $info[$i]["cn"][0] ?>');"><?php echo $info[$i]["cn"][0] ?></li>
        }
        if ($i == 0) {
        echo "No matches found!";
        } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#search').keyup(function () {
    var data = this.value.split(" ");
    var rows = $("#table tbody tr").hide();
    if(this.value ===""){
        rows.show();
        return;
    }
        rows.hide();
        rows.filter(function(i,v){
            var t = $(this);
            for (var d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
                if (t.is(":Contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
                    return false;
        }).show();
});
```

Comment: Hi Micaela. Thankyou for responding! Could you please elaborate more as to Where I should add this code?